# Why does Mac OS X not pass on duplicate USB messages to the App?

Tags: macos, usb, message, hid

We've observed that when attaching a device to Windows, all USB messages come and go as expected.  However under Mac OS X, a device returning the same data as the last message will be 'swallowed' and not passed on to the calling App.  On our device, we've taken to toggling a bit on every message we send back to ensure that these duplicates are not summarily deleted by the OS.  The device is NOT a mouse/keyboard however is using HID.

- Have others had similar experiences?
- Why does Mac OS X do this?
- Is there a way for the Mac OS X app to turn this 'de-duplication feature' off?